# Como refrescar Una pagina en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy queriendo exportar unos datos a excel pero al hacer esto la pagina queda procesando a pesar de que el excel ya esta generado y descargado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DataTable tab = new DataTable();
            int idAsesor = int.Parse(Session["userIdAsesor"].ToString());            
            tab = objR.ListarPorAsesor(idAsesor);
            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            gridView.DataSource = tab;
            gridView.DataBind();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Referidos.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                gridView.AllowPaging = false;                
                foreach (TableCell cell in gridView.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = gridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }

                foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }
                gridView.RenderControl(hw);
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();                
               Response.End();
            }
```

Comment: ¿En qué parte de tu código se llama a ese modal que dice procesando?

Comment: Creo que me he adelantado con la respuesta. ¿usas lenguaje web?

Comment: Pues si estoy usando el lenguaje web, el modal que esta llamado bajo busyboxdotnet en web.master

Comment: falta aportar algo de contexto, ese codigo que pones esta dentro de un eventos, digo como se invoca? estas realizando una llamada ajax usando el UpdatePanel ? porque si es asi no se puede enviar archivo como parte de la respuesta porque no hay un refresh de la pagina

Comment: Muchas gracias por su interes ya determine el inconveniente fue problema del componente busyboxdotnet  que estaba usando lo que no permitia que se refresque la pagina gracias.